# How do I parse microseconds with Time::Piece strptime?

Tags: perl

I have a timestamp that looks like `25-OCT-10 04.11.00.000000 AM`. I'm trying to convert this to a time format with

```
Time::Piece->strptime("25-OCT-10 04.11.00.000000 AM","%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%6N %p")
```

but it keeps throwing errors. I've tried `%OS`, `%SZ`. They dont seem to work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::Piece) doesn't support sub-second times.  Try [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) instead, for example, [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Strptime):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern => '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%6N %p',
);

my $dt = $parser->parse_datetime("25-OCT-10 04.11.00.000000 AM");
```

Answer (score 5):

`strptime` won't read that. `strptime` works with a structure that only goes down to integer seconds, and it doesn't have any formats for recognizing non-integer numerics -- and there's no such format as `N` in `Time::Piece`'s `strptime`. If you know that you're always expecting `.000000` for a number of microseconds then you could try using `..."%I.%M.%S.000000 %p"`, otherwise `strptime` just isn't for you.

How about [DateTime::Format::CLDR](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aCLDR)? A format of `"dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a"` seems to work perfectly well with that format.

```
use DateTime::Format::CLDR;
my $parser = DateTime::Format::CLDR->new(
    pattern => "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a",
    locale => "en_US",
);
my $dt = $parser->parse_datetime("25-OCT-10 04.11.00.000100 AM");

say $dt->iso8601; # 2010-01-25T04:11:00
```

**Edit:** just noticed that this doesn't recognize months properly if they're all uppercase -- it recognizes "Oct" but not "OCT". A fixed version is available [here](http://github.com/arodland/DateTime-Format-CLDR/tree/case-insensitive) and has been sent upstream for merge :)

**Update:** DateTime::Format::CLDR 1.11 is properly case-insensitive.

Comment: DateTime's strptime (in DateTime::Format::Strptime) does understand `%6N` to mean milliseconds.  But CLDR works too.

Comment: @cjm DateTime::Format::Strptime sounds like a fine interim fix then, thanks :)

Comment: I let the question's title confuse me.  `%6N` is microseconds, not milliseconds, and that's what Aks is actually trying to parse, so I updated the title for him.